# Load Data Infile for import CSV file not linear in MySQL

Tags: mysql, load-data-infile

I use MySql RDBMS

```
mysql> SELECT VERSION();
+------------------+
| VERSION()        |
+------------------+
| 5.1.51-community |
+------------------+
1 row in set
```

I need insert into one MySql table this CSV file updated each day and as pipeline delimited

```
||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||
|Table1|||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||            
||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||          
N|IDI  |TEST|START DATE HOUR    |CAUSE|KIND|NUMB|NAMES|         
1|10704|    |21/07/2020 15:05:54|L    |MT  |2786|NAV  |         
2|10660|    |21/07/2020 09:27:31|L    |MT  |4088|PIS  |     
||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||          
|Table2|||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||            
||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||          
N|IDI  |TEST|START DATE HOUR    |END DATE HOUR      |LENGHT  |RETURNS         |CAUSE|KIND|NUMB|NAMES|           
1|10710|    |21/07/2020 19:34:00|21/07/2020 20:19:09|00:45:09| -              |L    |MT  |7806|ACC  |
2|10708|    |21/07/2020 18:28:12|21/07/2020 18:28:13|00:00:01| -              |T    |MT  |2600|LIT  |       
3|10700|    |21/07/2020 14:16:37|21/07/2020 15:19:13|01:02:36|21/07/2020 17:00|L    |MT  |4435|UHI  |       
4|10698|    |21/07/2020 14:06:45|21/07/2020 14:07:22|00:00:37|-               |B    |MT  |5789|TYK  |
5|10674|    |21/07/2020 10:21:04|21/07/2020 10:44:41|00:23:37|21/07/2020 12:30|T    |MT  |6699|FGR  |
||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||
```

For insert in table this CSV using [LOAD DATA INFILE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/load-data.html)

```
TRUNCATE TABLE `table_csv`;

LOAD DATA INFILE 'C:/MySQL/Data/import.csv' 
IGNORE INTO TABLE `table_csv` 
FIELDS TERMINATED BY '|' ESCAPED BY '\\' IGNORE 3 LINES;
```

Note that the number of columns between table 1 and table 2 are different on CSV file

For table 1 the number of column is 8

For table 2 the number of column is 10

This is my problem

Because the import in MySql table is wrong

```
+---+-----+----+-------------------+-------------------+--------+-------------------+-----+----+----+-----+
| N |IDI  |TEST|START DATE HOUR    |END DATE HOUR      |LENGHT  |RETURNS            |CAUSE|KIND|NUMB|NAMES| 
| 1 |10704|    |2020-07-21 15:05:54|                   |00:00:00|                   |2786 |NAV |    |     |
| 2 |10660|    |2020-07-21 09:27:31|                   |00:00:00|                   |4088 |PIS |    |     |
| 1 |10710|    |2020-07-21 19:34:00|2020-07-21 20:19:09|00:45:09|                   |L    |MT  |7806|ACC  |
| 2 |10708|    |2020-07-21 18:28:12|2020-07-21 18:28:13|00:00:01|                   |T    |MT  |2600|LIT  |
| 3 |10700|    |2020-07-21 14:16:37|2020-07-21 15:19:13|01:02:36|2020-07-21 17:00:00|L    |MT  |4435|UHI  |
| 4 |10698|    |2020-07-21 14:06:45|2020-07-21 14:07:22|00:00:37|                   |B    |MT  |5789|TYK  |
| 5 |10674|    |2020-07-21 10:21:04|2020-07-21 10:44:41|00:23:37|21/07/2020 12:30:00|T    |MT  |6699|FGR  |
+---+-----+----+-------------------+-------------------+--------+-------------------+-----+----+----+-----+
```

The first two rows of table 1 have the data moved

```
+---+-----+----+-------------------+-------------------+--------+-------------------+-----+----+----+-----+
| N |IDI  |TEST|START DATE HOUR    |END DATE HOUR      |LENGHT  |RETURNS            |CAUSE|KIND|NUMB|NAMES| 
| 1 |10704|    |2020-07-21 15:05:54|                   |00:00:00|                   |2786 |NAV |    |     |
| 2 |10660|    |2020-07-21 09:27:31|                   |00:00:00|                   |4088 |PIS |    |     |
+---+-----+----+-------------------+-------------------+--------+-------------------+-----+----+----+-----+
```

Instead of

```
+---+-----+----+-------------------+-------------------+--------+-------------------+-----+----+----+-----+
| N |IDI  |TEST|START DATE HOUR    |END DATE HOUR      |LENGHT  |RETURNS            |CAUSE|KIND|NUMB|NAMES| 
| 1 |10704|    |2020-07-21 15:05:54|                   |00:00:00|                   |     |    |2786| NAV |
| 2 |10660|    |2020-07-21 09:27:31|                   |00:00:00|                   |     |    |4088| PIS |
+---+-----+----+-------------------+-------------------+--------+-------------------+-----+----+----+-----+
```

My table below

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `table_csv`;
CREATE TABLE `table_csv` (
  `N` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `IDI` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `TEST` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `START DATE HOUR` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `END DATE HOUR` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `LENGHT` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `RETURNS` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `CAUSE` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `KIND` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `NUMB` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `NAMES` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `ID` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  PRIMARY KEY (`ID`),
  UNIQUE KEY `IDI` (`IDI`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

[This the csv file](https://www.sitepoint.com/community/uploads/short-url/gDHMTA4cxMEGphQJMDnFBr3WuBB.csv)

result

[image]

Comment: You should split the csv file using whatever tool you are familiar with (python,java,php etc)

Comment: Thank you I use C# and DOTNET... any example pls?

Comment: Nope java isn't something I know.

Comment: ok, I have tried preprocess csv file into a proper CSV using C#, adding missing columns, but the output is in my first question...